# About continuity and clousure

Tags: general-topology

Let be $X$ an $Y$ topological spaces and $f:A\subseteq X\longrightarrow B \subseteq Y$ continuous. Then $f(\overline{U\cap A})\subseteq \overline{f(U\cap A)}$ for every $U\subseteq X.$

I know that if $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous then $f(\overline{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$ for every $A\subseteq X,$ but I have problems in the generalization of this result

Comment: Is $B$ an arbitrary subset of $Y$, or does the range of $f$ lie in $B$?

Comment: $B$ is an arbitrary subset of $Y$

Comment: If $B$ is empty set and $U = X$, then for example this is not true, right?

Comment: Ok, if the conclusion is $f(\overline{U\cap A})\subseteq \overline{f(U\cap A)}$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the closure "overline" denotes closure in $X$ or in $Y$...  We have $$f(\overline {U\cap A})=f(\overline {U\cap A}\cap A)=f(cl_A(U\cap A))\subset cl_B (f(U\cap A))=B\cap \overline {f(U\cap A)}\subset \overline {f(U\cap A)}.$$ The first equality is because $f(a)$ exists only for $a\in A.$ The first "$\subset$" is  by continuity of $f:A\to B.$

Answer (score 0):

Change the subset in your theorem to B. COnsider B equal to the intersection of U and A. Drink a beer.

Comment: $f$ is continuous only in $A.$

Comment: @Rigo That is not what it says in the problem but it is easy to verify that the intersection of U and A is a subset of A.